# converting kWh to kW in R

Tags: r, rate

I have a data from kWh meter that I want to convert to kW. Here is what I have done so far:

```
lines="timestamp,kwh
30-Nov-14 8:00:00 AM,23350
30-Nov-14 8:15:00 AM,23350
30-Nov-14 8:30:00 AM,23351
30-Nov-14 8:45:00 AM,23351
30-Nov-14 9:00:00 AM,23351
30-Nov-14 9:15:01 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 9:30:00 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 9:45:00 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 10:00:00 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 10:15:00 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 10:30:00 AM,23354
30-Nov-14 10:45:00 AM,23354
30-Nov-14 11:00:00 AM,23354
30-Nov-14 11:15:00 AM,23357
30-Nov-14 11:30:00 AM,23357
30-Nov-14 11:45:00 AM,23358
30-Nov-14 12:00:00 PM,23359
30-Nov-14 12:30:00 PM,23359
30-Nov-14 12:45:00 PM,23359
30-Nov-14 1:00:00 PM,23359"
df=read.table(text = lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
diff.kwh = diff(as.matrix(df$kwh))
# have to add NA so that the length is the same as df
df$diff.kwh=rbind("NA",diff.kwh)

library(zoo)
z = zoo(df[,2:3], as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format="%d-%b-%y %I:%M:%S %p"))
z
```

What I have is the following:

```
    > z
                    kwh   diff.kwh
2014-11-30 08:00:00 23350 NA
2014-11-30 08:15:00 23350 0
2014-11-30 08:30:00 23351 1
2014-11-30 08:45:00 23351 0
2014-11-30 09:00:00 23351 0
2014-11-30 09:15:01 23352 1
2014-11-30 09:30:00 23352 0
2014-11-30 09:45:00 23352 0
2014-11-30 10:00:00 23352 0
2014-11-30 10:15:00 23352 0
2014-11-30 10:30:00 23354 2
2014-11-30 10:45:00 23354 0
2014-11-30 11:00:00 23354 0
2014-11-30 11:15:00 23357 3
2014-11-30 11:30:00 23357 0
2014-11-30 11:45:00 23358 1
2014-11-30 12:00:00 23359 1
2014-11-30 12:30:00 23359 0
2014-11-30 12:45:00 23359 0
2014-11-30 13:00:00 23359 0
```

What I need to do is to get the (non-zero) value of diff.kwh column, and then divide each of the non-zero values by the (time) length of the preceeding zeros. This is where I am stuck. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Let say at 9:15, the kwh meter change values by 1 kWh, so at that time the diff.kWh is non-zero. The length of the preceeding zeros is two, as there are two zeros before this value. So the kW will be 1kWh divided by (2+1)*0.25. The number 2 is the length of zeros, and 0.25 is the timestep in hours. I may have messed up the diff.kwh column, probably by adding NA?

Comment: Note that the code above could be written: `library(zoo); fmt <- "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S %p"; kwh <- read.zoo(text = lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", tz = "", format = fmt); cbind(kwh, diff.kwh = diff(z, na.pad = FALSE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution based on data frames:

```
# Parse timestamp
df$timestamp.2 <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format="%d-%b-%y %I:%M:%S %p")

# Select records with non-zero diff.kwh
df2 <- df[df$diff.kwh!=0,]

# Get the differences between the corresponding timestamps
df2$delta.t <- c(NA,diff(df2$timestamp.2))

df2$kW <- with(df2,as.numeric(diff.kwh)/delta.t*60)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the answer from Marat Talipov above, I pasted here so that people knows the end results I need. Here it is:

```
lines="timestamp,kwh
30-Nov-14 8:00:00 AM,23350
30-Nov-14 8:15:00 AM,23350
30-Nov-14 8:30:00 AM,23351
30-Nov-14 8:45:00 AM,23351
30-Nov-14 9:00:00 AM,23351
30-Nov-14 9:15:01 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 9:30:00 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 9:45:00 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 10:00:00 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 10:15:00 AM,23352
30-Nov-14 10:30:00 AM,23354
30-Nov-14 10:45:00 AM,23354
30-Nov-14 11:00:00 AM,23354
30-Nov-14 11:15:00 AM,23357
30-Nov-14 11:30:00 AM,23357
30-Nov-14 11:45:00 AM,23358
30-Nov-14 12:00:00 PM,23359
30-Nov-14 12:30:00 PM,23359
30-Nov-14 12:45:00 PM,23359
30-Nov-14 1:00:00 PM,23359"
df=read.table(text = lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
diff.kwh = diff(as.matrix(df$kwh))
# have to add NA so that the length is the same as df
df$diff.kwh=rbind(NA,diff.kwh)
df

# Parse timestamp
df$timestamp.2 <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format="%d-%b-%y %I:%M:%S %p")

# Select records with non-zero diff.kwh
df2 <- df[df$diff.kwh!=0,]

# Remove NAs
df2 <- df2[complete.cases(df2),]

# Add the first row of the original df, so that the first value of diff.kwh counts
df2 = rbind(df[1,],df2)

# Get the differences between the corresponding timestamps
df2$delta.t <- c(NA,diff(df2$timestamp.2))

# Calculate kw, delta.t is in minutes
df2$kw <- with(df2,diff.kwh*60/delta.t)

# Create zoo
library(zoo)
z1 = zoo(df[,2:3], as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format="%d-%b-%y %I:%M:%S %p"))
z2 = zoo(df2$kw, df2$timestamp.2)
colnames(z2) = "kw"

# merge the two zoo, replacing NAs backward
z3 = na.locf(merge(z1,z2), fromLast=T)
```

Here is the result that I want:

```
> z3
                      kwh diff.kwh       kw
2014-11-30 08:00:00 23350        0 2.000000
2014-11-30 08:15:00 23350        0 2.000000
2014-11-30 08:30:00 23351        1 2.000000
2014-11-30 08:45:00 23351        0 1.332840
2014-11-30 09:00:00 23351        0 1.332840
2014-11-30 09:15:01 23352        1 1.332840
2014-11-30 09:30:00 23352        0 1.600356
2014-11-30 09:45:00 23352        0 1.600356
2014-11-30 10:00:00 23352        0 1.600356
2014-11-30 10:15:00 23352        0 1.600356
2014-11-30 10:30:00 23354        2 1.600356
2014-11-30 10:45:00 23354        0 4.000000
2014-11-30 11:00:00 23354        0 4.000000
2014-11-30 11:15:00 23357        3 4.000000
2014-11-30 11:30:00 23357        0 2.000000
2014-11-30 11:45:00 23358        1 2.000000
2014-11-30 12:00:00 23359        1 4.000000
2014-11-30 12:30:00 23359        0       NA
2014-11-30 12:45:00 23359        0       NA
2014-11-30 13:00:00 23359        0       NA
```